# GAE: Why are subclasses NOT instances of db.Model (parent)?

Tags: google-app-engine

Given:

```
class A:
 pass
class B(A):
 pass
```

`isinstance(B(), A)` will return True.

BUT

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    pass
```

`isinstance(MyModel(), db.Model)` returns `False`(surely `True`?).

What am I missing?

**Edit:**
Ok, simplest test that fails- created a blank GAE project. Inside main.py I've defined:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db  

class MyModel(db.Model):  
    detail = db.StringProperty()
```

Then I've created a test file (test_ami.py) which contains the following:

```
import unittest  
from main import MyModel  
from google.appengine.ext import db  

class TestAmI(unittest.TestCase):  
    def test_whatami(self):  
        m = MyModel()  
        self.assertEquals(True, isinstance(m, db.Model));  
        self.assertEquals(True, isinstance(MyModel(), db.Model));
```

On the command line: nosetests --with-gae results in:
File "test_ami.py", line 8, in test_whatami self.assertEquals(True, isinstance(m, db.Model)) AssertionError: True != False

Line 8 is: self.assertEquals(True, isinstance(m, db.Model));

Comment: More detail:

from google.appengine.ext import db
class Health(db.Model):
...

and then in a unit test

import unittest
from google.appengine.ext import db
from models.health import Health

class TestHealth(unittest.TestCase):
 def test_foo(self):
  h = Health();
  print isinstance(Health(), db.Model)
  print isinstance(h, db.Model)

Last two lines both print False

Answer (score 3):

> isinstance(B(), A) will return True.

That seems unlikely, since in your class definition, B doesn't extend A.

> isinstance(MyModel(), db.Model)
>   returns False(surely True?).

Testing this on shell.appspot.com, it returns True, as expected.

Comment: As I say, testing this on shell.appspot.com returns the expected result, so clearly you're doing something different from the example you've shown. You should reduce your own code to the simplest test case that reproduces the problem.

Comment: simplest test that fails.. yes, great idea- done that. still failing.

Comment: It still works just fine on shell.appspot.com. Try eliminating the testing framework and other variables.

Comment: well, i kinda need it pass with the unittest in place.. it's where the anomaly raised it's head in the first place. interestingly, if i declare MyModel in the same file as TestAmI, it passes. looks like it might be time for a different question soon...?